# Displaying an array in Xcode and parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, xcode

Im currently using following code to display an array inside of an UItextView / label / textfield :

```
  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"appMsg"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
            // Do something with the found objects
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSString *besked = object[@"besked"];
                msgRecieved0.text = besked;
                NSLog(@"Object values %@",[objects valueForKey:@"besked"]);

            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

i have tried to set the NSString to :

```
NSArray *besked = object[@"besked"];
                msgRecieved0.text = besked[0];
                msgRecieved1.text = besked[1];
                msgRecieved2.text = besked[2];
```

But again i get an error.

i have tried all i know, and i don't know what i should do to display a "list" of the arrays. I would like to show the first 10 values coming from the array

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: -[__NSCFString objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Have you put breakpoints in? Is besked storing the correct string?

Comment: There should be n breakpoints. beaked is stored as a string.

Comment: When just running: NSLog(@"Object values %@",[objects valueForKey:@"besked"]); I'm able to get all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFObject will not respond to Dictionary style element addressing. You must use keyValue coding style code.

Instead of `NSString *besked = object[@"besked"];`, try this:

```
NSString *besked = [object objectForKey:@"besked"];
```

Edit - This might be what you need, if the Parse object is an array.

```
NSArray* besked = [object objectForKey:@"besked"];
NSString*  str0 = [besked objectAtIndex:0];
NSString*  str1 = [besked objectAtIndex:1];
NSString*  str2 = [besked objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: expected method to read array element not found on object op type "NSString *"

Comment: What does "besked" store in your Parse database?

Comment: random messages like : how are you?, leaving for football, see you later ;), etc.

Comment: Then you cannot do: NSArray *besked = object[@"besked"]; it must be what I wrote.

Comment: but how do i then get more then the latest string?

Comment: i have inserted 'NSString *besked = [object objectForKey:@"besked"];' but my UItextView still only displays the last string. i would love to display the lastet 10 strings in my UItextView (if thats the outlet i should use)

Comment: @Tyler I don't think you're using the Parse database properly. Each PFObject contains one row. Are the strings on multiple rows?

Comment: no. Each row contains just one string.

When i run this code:
 NSString *besked = object[@"besked"];
                msgRecieved.text = besked;
                NSLog(@"Object values %@",[objects valueForKey:@"besked"]);

i get 28 values in the log, but only the latest string is being displayed in the UITextView

Comment: Try making the UITextView larger? Sounds like some of it is being truncated.

Comment: Also try: NSArray *besked = [object objectForKey:@"besked"];
Then access the individual elements. @Tyler

Comment: The Text view is almost the entire view. When setting it to NSarray and a specific element ([0]) I'm getting this message: -[__NSCFString objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xae8b0e0

Comment: What about:
`[besked objectAtIndex:0];`
@Tyler

Comment: Still saying: `-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: What kind of object is your Parse object? Is it a string or an array?

Comment: to the edit i get: no visible @interface for 'NSarray' declares the selector 'objectForIndex'

Comment: at parse.com besked is set to string

Comment: Then use the first thing I said, and you have to parse out the objects.

Comment: I got a working code from someone in here but now i only need to display the values. Im getting the correct values in NSLog and i have set the limit to 10 queries. How do i like "create" echo out the data in object C? If i would have made this in php i would echo out a div for each string. But i don't know how to do this in Xcode yet. Should i set an UIView/UITextView/UITableView or should i make some sort of "create" function to create new labels with strings? I know I'm neewbie at Objective C but I'm really glad for all your help ! :)

Comment: `PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"appMsg"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    query.limit =10;
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Retrive values like below,object id is retrieved by objects.objectId
            NSLog(@"Object values %@",[objects valueForKey:@"besked"]);
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];`

This is my current code

Comment: Add this to your (!error) section:

    `for(int i=0; i<[objects count]; ++i){
        UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        textView.text = [objects objectAtIndex:i];
        int frameHeight = 40;
        textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, i*frameHeight, self.view.frame.size.width, frameHeight);
        [self.view addSubview:textView];
    }`

Please mark answer as correct if you get the solution working. @Tyler